# Pandas slice into segements on condition and select

Tags: pandas

I have a quote dataframe in which '**delta**' column identifies rows in 'true'. I'd like to select those in 'true' in between 'false' lows and find lowest in 'low' and drop those are not. finally drop off all rows in 'false'.

```js
  symbol open high low close adjusted volume delta
date        
2017-11-06 TOU 23.70 25.09 23.70 25.07 24.7563 999400 False
2017-11-07 TOU 25.10 25.25 24.73 24.77 24.4600 546500 True
2017-11-08 TOU 24.75 25.16 24.41 24.90 24.5884 450000 True
2017-11-09 TOU 25.36 27.26 25.30 26.83 26.4942 2347500 False
2017-11-10 TOU 26.70 27.01 26.45 26.81 26.4745 903600 False
2017-11-13 TOU 26.76 26.85 26.10 26.40 26.0696 733200 False
2017-11-14 TOU 26.30 26.41 25.37 25.48 25.1611 619300 False
2017-11-15 TOU 25.22 25.27 24.72 24.74 24.4304 525800 False
2017-11-16 TOU 24.69 24.90 24.33 24.34 24.0354 516000 True
2017-11-17 TOU 24.67 24.86 23.98 24.00 23.6997 1233100 True
2017-11-20 TOU 24.01 24.03 23.68 23.70 23.4034 977800 True
2017-11-21 TOU 23.86 23.98 23.35 23.46 23.1664 544300 True
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2018-09-21 TOU 21.11 21.30 20.91 20.99 20.9900 1235800 True
2018-09-24 TOU 21.19 21.72 21.19 21.66 21.6600 995800 False
2018-09-25 TOU 21.83 21.83 21.45 21.45 21.4500 574100 False
2018-09-26 TOU 21.38 21.65 20.88 20.97 20.9700 791600 True
2018-09-27 TOU 21.36 22.69 21.23 22.67 22.6700 1192500 False
2018-09-28 TOU 22.58 23.27 22.29 22.74 22.7400 1376300 False
2018-10-01 TOU 23.15 23.86 22.75 23.01 23.0100 1137200 False
2018-10-02 TOU 23.05 23.05 22.51 22.59 22.5900 801600 False
2018-10-03 TOU 22.65 23.59 22.43 23.52 23.5200 1391100 False
2018-10-04 TOU 23.35 23.35 22.39 22.47 22.4700 1272900 False
2018-10-05 TOU 22.62 22.66 22.19 22.62 22.6200 668300 False
2018-10-09 TOU 22.70 23.44 22.53 23.41 23.4100 832800 False
2018-10-10 TOU 23.38 23.38 22.27 22.30 22.3000 1435300 False
2018-10-11 TOU 21.84 22.08 21.16 21.28 21.2800 1127700 False
2018-10-12 TOU 21.78 21.80 21.12 21.18 21.1800 887300 True
2018-10-15 TOU 21.32 21.42 20.58 20.68 20.6800 852300 True
2018-10-16 TOU 20.80 20.80 20.34 20.44 20.4400 1115200 True
2018-10-17 TOU 20.38 20.48 20.03 20.09 20.0900 700900 True
2018-10-18 TOU 20.00 20.01 19.32 19.50 19.5000 1188600 True
2018-10-19 TOU 19.59 20.15 19.57 19.94 19.9400 1321600 True
2018-10-22 TOU 19.96 20.08 19.73 19.80 19.8000 828200 True
```

Roughly resolved it by the following code:

```js
tdf = tdf.reset_index()
temp = tdf.iloc[0:0]
final = tdf.iloc[0:0]
for index, row in tdf.iterrows():
    if(row.delta == False):
        temp =  temp[temp.low ==  temp.low.min()]
        final = final.append(temp)
        temp = temp.iloc[0:0]
    elif(row.delta == True):
        temp = temp.append(row)
        if(row.date == tdf.iloc[-1].date):
            temp =  temp[temp.low ==  temp.low.min()]
            final = final.append(temp)
            temp = temp.iloc[0:0]
```

result from df final:

[image]

Please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I will proceed:

```
#creating the dataframe

import pandas as pd

from io import StringIO

s = '''date symbol  open    high    low close   adjusted    volume  delta
2017-11-06  TOU 23.70   25.09   23.70   25.07   24.7563 999400  False
2017-11-07  TOU 25.10   25.25   24.73   24.77   24.4600 546500  True
2017-11-08  TOU 24.75   25.16   24.41   24.90   24.5884 450000  True
2017-11-09  TOU 25.36   27.26   25.30   26.83   26.4942 2347500 False
2017-11-10  TOU 26.70   27.01   26.45   26.81   26.4745 903600  False
2017-11-13  TOU 26.76   26.85   26.10   26.40   26.0696 733200  False
2017-11-14  TOU 26.30   26.41   25.37   25.48   25.1611 619300  False
2017-11-15  TOU 25.22   25.27   24.72   24.74   24.4304 525800  False
2017-11-16  TOU 24.69   24.90   24.33   24.34   24.0354 516000  True
2017-11-17  TOU 24.67   24.86   23.98   24.00   23.6997 1233100 True
2017-11-20  TOU 24.01   24.03   23.68   23.70   23.4034 977800  True
2017-11-21  TOU 23.86   23.98   23.35   23.46   23.1664 544300  True
2018-09-21  TOU 21.11   21.30   20.91   20.99   20.9900 1235800 True
2018-09-24  TOU 21.19   21.72   21.19   21.66   21.6600 995800  False
2018-09-25  TOU 21.83   21.83   21.45   21.45   21.4500 574100  False
2018-09-26  TOU 21.38   21.65   20.88   20.97   20.9700 791600  True
2018-09-27  TOU 21.36   22.69   21.23   22.67   22.6700 1192500 False
2018-09-28  TOU 22.58   23.27   22.29   22.74   22.7400 1376300 False
2018-10-01  TOU 23.15   23.86   22.75   23.01   23.0100 1137200 False
2018-10-02  TOU 23.05   23.05   22.51   22.59   22.5900 801600  False
2018-10-03  TOU 22.65   23.59   22.43   23.52   23.5200 1391100 False
2018-10-04  TOU 23.35   23.35   22.39   22.47   22.4700 1272900 False
2018-10-05  TOU 22.62   22.66   22.19   22.62   22.6200 668300  False
2018-10-09  TOU 22.70   23.44   22.53   23.41   23.4100 832800  False
2018-10-10  TOU 23.38   23.38   22.27   22.30   22.3000 1435300 False
2018-10-11  TOU 21.84   22.08   21.16   21.28   21.2800 1127700 False
2018-10-12  TOU 21.78   21.80   21.12   21.18   21.1800 887300  True
2018-10-15  TOU 21.32   21.42   20.58   20.68   20.6800 852300  True
2018-10-16  TOU 20.80   20.80   20.34   20.44   20.4400 1115200 True
2018-10-17  TOU 20.38   20.48   20.03   20.09   20.0900 700900  True
2018-10-18  TOU 20.00   20.01   19.32   19.50   19.5000 1188600 True
2018-10-19  TOU 19.59   20.15   19.57   19.94   19.9400 1321600 True
2018-10-22  TOU 19.96   20.08   19.73   19.80   19.8000 828200  True'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\t', index_col=0)
```

Limiting the data between first and last `False` in delta column, as my `True` must be sandwiched between `False` values.

```
df1 = df[df[df.delta==False].index.min():df[df.delta==False].index.max()]
```

Converting the `delta` column to integer and flipping its value. Reason for this will become clear below:

```
df1['deltaInt'] = df1.delta.astype('int')
df1.deltaInt = 1 - df1.deltaInt
```

Adding a cumulative sum column;

```
df1['cumSum'] = df1.deltaInt.cumsum()
```

Removing the first row;

```
df1 = df1.iloc[1:,:]
```

Aggregating by cumsum and selecting the lowest value in column low;

```
df2 = df1.groupby('cumSum').apply(lambda x:x[x.low==x.low.min()])
```

Selecting only the rows which have delta as true, gives us the desired result;

```
df2 = df2[df2.delta]
print(df2)
```

Output:

[image]

Of course you can drop the two extra columns. Hope this helps, this is not an optimised code, but the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: missing last segment of true's

Comment: Because it is not sandwiched between two false